# Numba 2 typing errors

Tags: python, optimization, numba

Given an array `arr` consisting solely of floats,
I want to calculate the difference of every element with all elements before it, as another simple array (`dists`in the code):

```
@njit
def calc_dists(arr):
  dists=np.array([1])
  for i,j in enumerate(arr[1:]):
    dists=np.append(dists, [j-k for k in arr[:i]])
  return dists[1:]
```

The creation of an empty `dists` array inside the function led to a typing error from numba, which is why I do it like that now. However, I now get the following error:

> TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> Cannot unify array(int64, 1d, C) and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'dists.2', defined at  (7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array([1])` is an integer-typed array because it contains one integer item. Since `arr` contains floats, `k` is a float and so `j-k` (due to the float promotion of `j` caused by the binary operation and the semantic rule of Python). Consequently `dists` is appended with a list containing floats while the array contains integers. This is forbidden in Numba.

The question is either you want the output array to contains integer or floats. Assuming this is floats, a simple fix is to use `dists=np.array([1.0])` instead. However, the best solution is to always specify the types of Numpy array with Numba (preventing many bugs) using `dists=np.array([1], dtype=np.float64)`.

That being said, the code is not efficient. You should avoid using `np.append` in a loop as much as possible as it recreate a new array (and copy the preview content) again and again. Using lists is not efficient too. You can preallocate the `dist` array to the right size and fill it with direct access and two `for` loops (note that `for` loops are cheap in Numba as opposed to a pure-CPython code).

Comment: Thanks, I eventually worked it out myself, but your additional commentary is worth gold!